# Why PDO is not connecting to database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm fairly new to PDO, earlier I always used `mysql` or `mysqli` but I somehow learned about PDO by reading articles online and finally I generated this commen script to connect from database.
Here is my complete code which I wrote myself.

```
<?php   
 function connection() {
   try {
     $host = "localhost";
     $charset = "utf8";
     $user = "my_username";
     $pass = "my_pass";
     $db = "my_db_name";
     $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";

     $options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     $conn = new PDO ($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);

     } catch (PDOException $e) {
         $output = "We are unable to connect from database";
         $file = "error_log.php";
         $err_msg = $e->getMessage() " This error occured on <?php echo date("d/m/y i:m:s A");?>";
         file_put_contents($file, $err_msg);
         include 'inc/script-error.php';
     }
         $output = "Connection with database was successfull.";
         include 'inc/script-success.php';
 }
?>
```

Now first of all this script is not working and I also want to ask some questions
1. Why I need to bind this database `try` `catch` block into a `function`?
2. How I perform `order_by` and `group_by` complex queries with `PDO`?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168120/mysql-pdo-connection-to-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have PDO extension installed with php

Exec in command line : **php -m**

And search for **pdo_mysql** if exist


Here an example with ORDER BY & GROUP BY:

```
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
    $stmt = $db->prepare( "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE conditions GROUP BY col_name ORDER BY col_name2 ASC;" ) ;
    $stmt->execute();
    var_dump( $stmt->fetchAll() );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You welcome, if it help you, please check it :)