# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'invalid data source name'

Tags: php, fatal-error

I know there are many question regarding on stackoverflow but i read them all but my didn't fixed, so i asked new question. I have a file named as article.php and i have the this code init. Just a code which is showing error.

```
public static function getById( $id ) {
$conn = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
$sql = "SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate FROM articles WHERE id = :id";
$st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
$st->bindValue( ":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
$st->execute();
$row = $st->fetch();
$conn = null;
if ( $row ) return new Article( $row );
```

I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'invalid data source name' in C:\wamp64\www\classes\Article.php on line 102
( ! ) PDOException: invalid data source name in C:\wamp64\www\cms\classes\Article.php on line 102
```

My config file looks like

```
ini_set( "display_errors", true );
define( "DB_HOST", "localhost" );
define( "DB_USERNAME", "username" );
define( "DB_PASSWORD", "" );
define('DB_NAME', 'name');
```

Can you tell me why this happens and where i am doing mistake. Thanks

Comment: Reading the manual is always a good idea before posting: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php  SO Links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369360/how-to-properly-set-up-a-pdo-connection and https://stackoverflow.com/a/13168315/2943403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code seems to be used before with `mysql` or `mysqli` connector, however `PDO` is way more generic and supports multiple database vendors and not just MySQL. So you need to tell `PDO` which db to connect, etc.

So `PDO` fails to make connection with only db name, your `DB_HOST` must be similar to this:

`define('DB_HOST','mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb');`

More options to connect:

```
mysql:host=localhost;port=3307;dbname=testdb
mysql:unix_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock;dbname=testdb
```

> getting this error mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

You don't need this since you are using PDO. Use PDO's API instead.

Comment: can please expand the answer

Comment: now i am getting this error  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Comment: $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate FROM articles
            ORDER BY " . mysqli_real_escape_string( $order) . " LIMIT :numRows";

Comment: @yoyoy Don't mix APIs.  Use prepared statements.  Research MORE before asking for help here.

Comment: what to do now with this code
'$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate FROM articles ORDER BY " . mysqli_real_escape_string( $order) . " LIMIT :numRows'''

Comment: Use placeholders for both.  Read this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/how-to-apply-bindvalue-method-in-limit-clause

Comment: @mickmackusa this is a platform for helping not just saying just go and do research. you don't have an answer then why posting comments.

Comment: @mickmackusa i have no time to read these questions. please leave the discussion

Comment: If you are a developer, act like one.  People have already answered your issues, just look uo the answers. Don't waste volunteers' time re-asking questions.