# connect php to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

please, could someone help me what is my mistake? Creating a database works well but when I create a table it makes this SQLSTATE error[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected
Here are the codes:

```
<? php
$server = 'localhost';
$login = 'root';
$password = '';
try{
  $connexion = new PDO('mysql:host = $server; dbname=test', $login, $password);
  $connexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $connexion->exec("CREATE TABLE utilisateur(nom varchar(50))");
  echo 'Réussi';
}
catch(PDOException $e){
  echo 'Echec de la connexion : '.$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql PDO connection to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168120/mysql-pdo-connection-to-database)

Comment: It's not a duplicate @ZainFarooq. Two completely different issues

Comment: is there really a space in this `<? php` ? You also have other issues in your connection declaration.

Comment: Remove the spaces in your connection string - `'mysql:host=$server;dbname=test'`

Comment: Try and use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default "string" field. Anything shorter can and will lead to unexpected trunacation issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the error says:

> 'No database selected'

Before you can create a table you must select which database it's being created in. If you're creating the table manually you'd login to your mysql server, and then in mysql server you'd type this:

```
USE dbname;
```

Since you're likely looking to create the table within php you should already have logged into the mysql server under the database you want:

> $connexion = new PDO('mysql:host = $server; **dbname=test**', $login, $password);

If that database does not exist already you need to create it using this command:

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname;
```